# how to select the action in UIButton in objective-c

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have 12 `UIButton` in the `UIView` .I need to select only the 5 IBOutLet Action of UIButton then after the 5th action it should show the alert controller.
If i select less than 5th UIButton action it should show the alert message as choose 5 images .how to do?

Comment: Use tableview instead of 12 buttons and check selected rows of the tableview.

Comment: Use a `var count : Int = 0`, increase count on each action.

Comment: thanks....to reply